# how to install dlib library in anaconda?

Tags: python, face-recognition, dlib

Collecting dlib
  Using cached dlib-19.19.0.tar.gz (3.2 MB)
Building wheels for collected packages: dlib
  Building wheel for dlib (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'D:\anaconda\envs\env_dlib\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-hlayhizn\dlib\setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-hlayhizn\dlib\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-sam_vsqz'
       cwd: C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-hlayhizn\dlib\
  Complete output (53 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  package init file 'dlib__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
  running build_ext
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-hlayhizn\dlib\setup.py", line 120, in get_cmake_version
      out = subprocess.check_output(['cmake', '--version'])
    File "D:\anaconda\envs\env_dlib\lib\subprocess.py", line 411, in check_output
      **kwargs).stdout
    File "D:\anaconda\envs\env_dlib\lib\subprocess.py", line 488, in run
      with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
    File "D:\anaconda\envs\env_dlib\lib\subprocess.py", line 800, in **init**
      restore_signals, start_new_session)
    File "D:\anaconda\envs\env_dlib\lib\subprocess.py", line 1207, in _execute_child
      startupinfo)
  FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "", line 1, in 
    File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-hlayhizn\dlib\setup.py", line 261, in 
      'Topic :: Software Development',
    File "D:\anaconda\envs\env_dlib\lib\site-packages\setuptools__init__.py", line 144, in setup
      return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
    File "D:\anaconda\envs\env_dlib\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
      dist.run_commands()
    File "D:\anaconda\envs\env_dlib\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
      self.run_command(cmd)
    File "D:\anaconda\envs\env_dlib\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "D:\anaconda\envs\env_dlib\lib\site-packages\wheel\bdist_wheel.py", line 223, in run
      self.run_command('build')
    File "D:\anaconda\envs\env_dlib\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "D:\anaconda\envs\env_dlib\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "D:\anaconda\envs\env_dlib\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
      self.run_command(cmd_name)
    File "D:\anaconda\envs\env_dlib\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "D:\anaconda\envs\env_dlib\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-hlayhizn\dlib\setup.py", line 129, in run
      cmake_version = self.get_cmake_version()
    File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-hlayhizn\dlib\setup.py", line 125, in get_cmake_version
      "\n*******************************************************************\n")
  RuntimeError:

---

CMake must be installed to build the following extensions: dlib

---

---

ERROR: Failed building wheel for dlib
  Running setup.py clean for dlib
Failed to build dlib
Installing collected packages: dlib
    Running setup.py install for dlib ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'D:\anaconda\envs\env_dlib\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-hlayhizn\dlib\setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-hlayhizn\dlib\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-77ybyx6j\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'D:\anaconda\envs\env_dlib\Include\dlib'
         cwd: C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-hlayhizn\dlib\
    Complete output (55 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    package init file 'dlib__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
    running build_ext
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-hlayhizn\dlib\setup.py", line 120, in get_cmake_version
        out = subprocess.check_output(['cmake', '--version'])
      File "D:\anaconda\envs\env_dlib\lib\subprocess.py", line 411, in check_output
        **kwargs).stdout
      File "D:\anaconda\envs\env_dlib\lib\subprocess.py", line 488, in run
        with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
      File "D:\anaconda\envs\env_dlib\lib\subprocess.py", line 800, in **init**
        restore_signals, start_new_session)
      File "D:\anaconda\envs\env_dlib\lib\subprocess.py", line 1207, in _execute_child
        startupinfo)
    FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

```
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-hlayhizn\dlib\setup.py", line 261, in <module>
    'Topic :: Software Development',
  File "D:\anaconda\envs\env_dlib\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 144, in setup
    return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
  File "D:\anaconda\envs\env_dlib\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "D:\anaconda\envs\env_dlib\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "D:\anaconda\envs\env_dlib\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "D:\anaconda\envs\env_dlib\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py", line 61, in run
    return orig.install.run(self)
  File "D:\anaconda\envs\env_dlib\lib\distutils\command\install.py", line 545, in run
    self.run_command('build')
  File "D:\anaconda\envs\env_dlib\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "D:\anaconda\envs\env_dlib\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "D:\anaconda\envs\env_dlib\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
    self.run_command(cmd_name)
  File "D:\anaconda\envs\env_dlib\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "D:\anaconda\envs\env_dlib\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-hlayhizn\dlib\setup.py", line 129, in run
    cmake_version = self.get_cmake_version()
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-hlayhizn\dlib\setup.py", line 125, in get_cmake_version
    "\n*******************************************************************\n")
RuntimeError:
*******************************************************************
 CMake must be installed to build the following extensions: dlib
*******************************************************************

----------------------------------------
```

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'D:\anaconda\envs\env_dlib\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-hlayhizn\dlib\setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-hlayhizn\dlib\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-77ybyx6j\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'D:\anaconda\envs\env_dlib\Include\dlib' Check the logs for full command output.

Answer (score 0):

Run the following command in Anaconda Prompt.

`easy_install dlib`